# Converting and playing of *.cvf format audio (samsung) files

Tags: audio, audio-conversion

I have some old audio `*.cvf` format (*Samsung*) files that I need to Convert and play.

I do not find any player or converter who can do it.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Some quick research suggests this type of file is actually a voicemail recording from some software called "Jet-VoiceMail" by Cowon America.

They provide some software called JetAudio with two versions available (Free and paid for Pro version). The [download page](http://www.cowonamerica.com/download/) on their site suggests that the free version is capable of opening any audio format and converting it to a more popular format (I would suggest WAV or OGG).

[image: Screenshot of JetAudio]